# Solve Partial Differential Equation using Eigenvectors

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve a quasi-linear PDE from a tutorial sheet using eigenvectors.

$(11x + 9y - 6u)
\partial u/
\partial x
+ (4u - 6x - 4y)
\partial u/
\partial y
= 3(x + y), u(3s - 1, 1 - 2s) = 0$

I am supposed to start by calculating the eigenvectors of the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 
11 & -6 & 3\\
9 & -4 & 3\\
-6 & 4 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Which can be found to be:
$
2\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
-3\\
\end{pmatrix},
 2\begin{pmatrix} 
2\\
3\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} ,
3\begin{pmatrix} 
3\\
3\\
-2\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I think you should start by setting up the ODEs for the characteristic curves. *Then* you can start thinking about how to solve them (using linear algebra, for example, since they will be linear in this case).

Comment: By the way, shouldn't that matrix be transposed?